# Error al recorrer un array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente codigo en js donde envio 2 array mediantes ajax

```
var first_array = {
  "warehouse": $("#warehouse").val(),
  "pricelist": $("#pricelist").val(),
  "date": $("#date").val(),
  "docstatus": "DR",
  "paymentterm": $("#paymentterm").val()
}

var second_array = []; 
$("#table_main tbody > tr").each(function() {
  var celdas = $(this).find('td');
  second_array.push({
    "line": $(celdas[0]).html(),
    "code": $(celdas[1]).html()
  });
});

$.ajax({
  data: {
    order: first_array,
    order_line: second_array
  },
  url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>main/save_data",
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  success: function(response) {

  },
  error: function() {
    toastr.error('ERROR', '', {
      progressBar: true,
      closeButton: true
    });
  }
});
```

Los datos del segundo array los enviá de la siguiente forma.

```
order_line[0][line] = 1
order_line[0][code] = 11111
order_line[1][line] = 2
order_line[1][code] = 2222
```

En mi archivo PHP declaro de la siguiente forma.

```
$docstatus  = trim($this->input->post('order[docstatus]', TRUE));
  $array = $this->input->post('order_line[]', TRUE);

  foreach ($array  as $val) {
     
      $line = $val->line;
     
    }
echo $line;
```

Este me muestra este error

```
Message: Trying to get property 'line' of non-object
```

Comment: Hazle un `var_dump($array)` después de recuperarlo por `post()` y seguramente te des cuenta de lo que te está pasando.

Comment: No se ve qué es lo que tienes en `$array`,  si un array en sí, ni se ve si dentro de él hay objetos, pero al menos debes ponerlo así: `foreach ($array as $val) {` sobra el signo `=`

Comment: @A.Cedano editado ya

Comment: ¿Sigue saliendo el mismo error? Como dice @phpMyGuel muestra el resultado de `var_dump($array);` pues no se sabe lo que hay en esa variable. Si es el array de más arriba, tienes que ponerlo así: `$val["line"]` que es la notación para leer arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Estas asumiendo erróneamente que lo que tienes es un arreglo de objetos

```
 foreach ($array  as $val) {
    $line = $val['line'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Probaste asi:

```
$array = $this->input->post('order_line', TRUE);
```

Comment: Hola Claudio, explica por qué sería esa la solución. Tu respuesta es de baja calidad.

Comment: Hola Claudio, las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle (¿qué hace esa línea? ¿cómo soluciona el problema? ¿dónde iría?). Lee [answer] y visita el [tour] para más información.